# Uniformly distributed data in d dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy

How can I generate a uniformly distributed [-1,1]^d data in Python? E.g. d is a dimension like 10.

I know how to generate uniformly distributed data like  np.random.randn(N) but dimension thing is confused me a lot.

Comment: `randn` will return samples of the normal distribution, not the uniform distribution. My gut feeling is that for a multivariate uniform distribution you can just use a product of `d` univariate uniform distributions but I'm not absolutely certain.

Comment: This question is unclear; the accepted answer seems to be a uniform distribution, but the question asks for a a gaussian/normal distribution http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming independence of the individual coordinates, then the following will generate a random point in `[-1, 1)^d`

```
np.random.random(d) * 2 - 1
```

The following will generate `n` observations, where each row is an observation

```
np.random.random((n, d)) * 2 - 1
```

Comment: Thanks. got exactly what I expected. I needed 2d samples in range -5 to 5 .  So, I used np.random.random((n,2)) * 10 - 5.

Answer (score 8):

As has been pointed out, randn produces normally distributed number (aka Gaussian).  To get uniformly distributed you should use "uniform".

If you just want a single sample at a time of 10 uniformly distributed numbers you can use:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.uniform(low=-1,high=1,size=10)
```

OR if you'd like to generate lots (e.g. 100) of them at once then you can do:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.random.uniform(low=-1,high=1,size=(100,10))
```

Now X[0], X[1], ... each has length 10.

Answer (score 2):

You can import the `random` module and call `random.random` to get a random sample from [0, 1). You can double that and subtract 1 to get a sample from [-1, 1).

Draw d values this way and the tuple will be a uniform draw from the cube [-1, 1)^d.

Answer (score 2):

Without numpy:

```
[random.choice([-1,1]) for _ in range(N)]
```

There may be reasons to use numpy's internal mechanisms, or use `random()` manually, etc. But those are implementation details, and also related to how the random number generation rations the bits of entropy the operating system provides.

Comment: Hmm, I think I was downvoted by someone because the OP did not clearly state he was looking for a uniform distribution of the form [-1,1]x[-1,1]x...x[-1,1], not a uniform distribution amongst the values of [-1,-1]^d (that is, {-1,1}^d). Since I feel the OP's question was extremely vague (OP thinks that the function they want is uniform when it is actually a gaussian), and that the syntax was not clear, and that my interpretation is reasonable, I'll just leave this here in case someone else finds it useful.